# Postfix myhostname change

Tags: ip, postfix, hostname

I'm currently trying to change the `myhostname` field.

So, I have this situation:

My server doesn't need an Internet domain anymore, since it will be a local host server.
But I want to serve mail sending or receiving through IP.
I am using Samba too, it's a developing server. Please, feel free to ask more details, if you need them.

My config looks like this (I have pasted just what I think is important, feel free to ask for more details):

```
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination = subdomain.domain.biz, localhost.localdomain, , localhost
mynetworks = 10.0.0.0/8 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
mynetworks_style = host
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject
myhostname = subdomain.domain.biz
mydomain = domain.biz
```

My questions are:

Can I change `myhostname` to be the actual IP?

If yes, what it will happen since I am using to serve for some computers?

It will require a reboot? (Hope not!)

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `domain.biz` to any local name (e.d. `server.local`).

What will happens after:

1. Your server cannot anymore send and receive emails to/from `domain.biz` domain;
2. You can use this server to send emails to other server in LAN and internet but for internet hosts your server will regorganize as untrusted (because you use local names). Emails into LAN will be send/receive successfully in most cases (because most servers consider LAN as trusted area. See `mynetworks` option in your config as example);
3. You will see in inbound emails `some_user@hostname.server.local` sender

You don't need to reboot server, execute command to reload configuration changes:

```
postfix reload
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

I have a few more questions, if you can help me...

It seem I am receiving bouncing e-mails to the old hostname... Should I edit the /etc/hosts too?


127.0.0.1 localhost
10.0.0.1 something.something.biz server

Comment: Yes, you need to edit `/etc/hosts`. Command `hostname -f` should return fqdn `hostname.server.local` but not `subdomain.domain.biz`

Comment: I will do it. But it will mess with Samba or other connected devices? It's a small network, at least 10 computers... Getting internet through a router, giving internet through a switch... That's what I am afraid of... Messing with the actual state of the network.

Comment: Oh, forgot to say I have Apache and PHP too... :) But I guess you got it...

Comment: Have you tested the solution?